# React testing libray access Provider properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have this StakeSelection.tsx component

```js
 <StakeProvider>
     <StakeInput
      fieldName="flexibleStake"
      data-testid="stake-input-flexi"
                />
    
     <StakeProvider>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

What happens here is `StakeInput` is an MUI `TextField` where the user can add values.
When the user focuses on the `input field (onFocus event)` StakeProvider has a prop called `stayFocused` that prop should be true.

I need to test two things.

1. Component renders correctly.
2. `stayFocused` should be true when user fire the focus event.

**This is my test file**

```js
import React from "react";
import { render, fireEvent, screen } from "@testing-library/react";

import StakeInput from "./stake-input";
import { StakeProvider } from "../../context/Stake";

describe("stakeInput", () => {
  const getRenderedComponent = () => {
    render(
      <StakeProvider>
        <StakeInput fieldName="stake" data-testid="stake-input" />
      </StakeProvider>
    );
  };

  it("should render correctly", () => {
    getRenderedComponent();

    expect(screen.getByTestId("stake-input")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  it("When the input is on focus stayFocused should be true", () => {
    getRenderedComponent();

    const input = screen.getByTestId("stake-input");

    fireEvent.focus(input);
    expect(input).toHaveFocus();

    // check stayFocused is true
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**This is my Stake context**

```js
import { createContext, useState, useContext } from "react";

const StakeContext = createContext({
  stake: 0,
  changeStake: (stake) => {},
  removeLastStake: () => {},
  focusedFieldName: "",
  setFocus: (name) => {},
  flexibleStake: "",
  stayFocused: false,
  removeFocus: () => {},
});

export const useStake = () => {
  const context = useContext(StakeContext);

  if (!context) {
    throw new Error(`useStake must be used within a StakeProvider`);
  }

  return context;
};

export const StakeProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [stake, setStake] = useState("");
  const [flexibleStake, setFlexibleStake] = useState("");
  const [focusedFieldName, setFocusedFieldName] = useState("");
  const [stayFocused, setStayFocused] = useState(false);

  const changeStake = (stake) => {
    if (focusedFieldName === "stake") {
      setStake((prev) => `${prev}${stake}`);
    } else {
      setFlexibleStake((prev) => `${prev}${stake}`);
    }
  };

  const removeLastStake = () => {
    if (focusedFieldName === "stake") {
      setStake((prev) => prev.slice(0, -1));
    } else {
      setFlexibleStake((prev) => prev.slice(0, -1));
    }
  };

  const setFocus = (name) => {
    setFocusedFieldName(name);
    setStayFocused(true);
  };

  const removeFocus = () => {
    setFocusedFieldName("");
    setStayFocused(false);
  };

  return (
    <StakeContext.Provider
      value={{
        stake,
        changeStake,
        removeLastStake,
        focusedFieldName,
        setFocus,
        removeFocus,
        flexibleStake,
        stayFocused,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </StakeContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

How do I achieve this with React and RTL?